# Does sklearn.pipeline support branching?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Suppose I have two pipelines:

```
pipln1 = Pipeline([("trsfm1",transformer_1),
                   ("trsfm2",transformer_2),
                   ("estmtr1",estimator_1)])

pipln2 = Pipeline([("trsfm1",transformer_1),
                   ("trsfm3",transformer_3),
                   ("estmtr2",estimator_2)])
```

The two linear pipelines share the same step, `trsfm1`.

Is it possible to avoid calculating `trsfm1` for twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would something like

`vect = transformer_1()` #Or whatever is is meant to do!

`vX = vect.fit_transform(Xtrain)` or whichever appropriate way you apply the `transformer_1`

and THEN

```
pipln1 = Pipeline([("trsfm2",transformer_2),
                   ("estmtr1",estimator_1)])

pipln2 = Pipeline([("trsfm3",transformer_3),
                   ("estmtr2",estimator_2)])
```

and then apply the two `Pipeline` on `vX`